# Reconstruct HTTP browsing from pcap

Tags: http, network-programming, pcap

I'm currently trying to automatically reconstruct an HTTP browsing only with a pcap ( basically it means matching an HTTP reply to the next HTTP requests). Most of the times, it works fine but sometimes a certain url, u, is present in the data of multiple HTTP replies.

For example, if u1 and u2 contains u in their reply data and if the request to u happens after the request to u2, how can I decide if the request to u was caused by u1 or by u2 ? Note that no request to u was made between u1 and u2.

Are there some fields in any network layer that I can use to make this match ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP runs on top of TCP, which is connection-oriented.  You have access to the IP header of the connection used for the HTTP request (client IP/port -> server IP/Port).

HTTP is a command/response protocol, there is 1 response for each request.

So, simply look for an HTTP response immediately following the HTTP request on the same TCP connection (server IP/Port -> client IP/Port).

HTTP is state-less, the connection may be closed between requests without affecting the overall browsing model (closing connections is the required behavior in HTTP 0.9, is the default behavior in HTTP 1.0, and is not the default behavior in HTTP 1.1+), so it is possible for an HTTP response to trigger subsequent requests on new connections, so you need to be ready to handle that.  The `Connection` header in the HTTP request will tell you whether the client is asking for the connection to remain open or not.  The `Connection` header in the HTTP response will tell you whether the server is actually closing the connection or not after sending the response.  But even if the server leaves the connection open, that is no *guarantee* that the client will actually reuse the same connection for later requests to the same server (though it likely will, unless a timeout elapses between requests).

Comment: Thanks for these explanations. Actually, I try to match responses with requests and not the contrary (I use tcptrace to split the different TCP sessions).

What I understand is that for requests to the same server as the previous response, the client can use or not the same connection and will always start a new connection for a different server. It means there is not a "network" way to associate differents HTTP packets which belongs to different TCP connections.

Comment: If you have split the TCP connections, matching responses with requests is easy, they are always on the same connection as each other. Starting with a response, look for a request that immediately precedes it on the same connection.

Comment: Trying to match related requests across multiple connections is more difficult. No, there is no definitive network-only identifier to tie them together. You could compare the client IP (the port is usually random) and server IP/Port of packets within a given timeframe. But you will more likely need to analyze the actual HTTP request/response data looking for thinks like HTTP redirects to new URLs, checking if requests have a `Referer` header matching the URL of previous responses, tracking the flow of HTTP cookies, etc.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. The problem appears when the same website is browsed twice in the same time and that's what I tried to explain in my first post.

If url u is in the data of reply to url1 and reply to url2. If request to url u happens after the two replies, I cannot decide if it was caused by the reply to url1 or by the reply tp url2. According to what you said, it seems there is not a real solution, whitout using an heuristic, to solve this problem.

Comment: Does it really matter? What if the user browses to `url1`, gets a response containing `u`, then the user manually browses to `u` (bookmark, type into address bar, etc) so it is not an automated request, and `u` is on the same server as `url1`, and the connection timeout has not elapsed yet so the browser reuses an existing connection to the server. The two sessions are not really related, but how are you going to know one way or the other?

Comment: You can't really reconstruct everything perfectly. Like I said, HTTP is stateless, each request acts standalone, the underlying connection is not important. The only data that really persists between related requests are the `Referer` request header and session cookies (assuming the browser has cookies enabled).